# Update changes every row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, oledb, crud

Im relatively new to c# and im working on a project at my university, which consist in verifying a switchboard, im working on CRUD right now to edit, create and delete items for one column in a datagridview, so here is my problem.

i have a button that works as my update on my crud, it takes the text from a textbox and replace the text in a row for the text in the textbox, so basically when i click on the row i want to change and then type the new text, when i click the button to update, it updates all the rows on my datagridview, so my objective is to edit only one row with the text from the textbox.

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Verificacao de Quadros 
                         Eletricos\Verificação de Quadros Elétricos\bin\Debug\DatabaseENG.accdb";
        string comando = @"UPDATE [Norms Table] 
                         set [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2)]
                         = @drills";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strcon))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(comando, con))
            {
                com.Parameters.Add("@drills", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Drill succesfully edited");

                }
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so heres the code of the update, thanks for your time.

Comment: The `UPDATE` query needs a `WHERE` clause to limit what is updated. Typically, this may look something like `WHERE id = 3`, or whatever the primary/unique key/value reference might be named. Without that, _every row_ will definitely get updated.

Comment: so it´s going to be `@"UPDATE FROM [Norms Table] where [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2)] = @drills";`?

Comment: Not quite: `UPDATE [Norms Table] SET ... WHERE ...`

Comment: `string comando = @"UPDATE [Norms Table] SET [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2)] WHERE = @drills";`

Comment: what is wrong here?, what should i put before '='?

Comment: The field that filter needs to be applied to. `UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = something WHERE ID=somerecordID`

Comment: Could you help me build my WHERE clause? `string comando = @"UPDATE [Norms Table] SET [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2) = @drills WHERE = ";` I really don't know what to put here

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, the query needs a `WHERE` clause.

So, based on your query:

```
UPDATE [Norms Table] 
   SET [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2)] = @drills
```

... would need an added where clause:

```
UPDATE [Norms Table] 
   SET [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2)] = @drills
 WHERE id = @id
```

The `id` portion in the where clause needs to match the primary key column reference from the `Norms Table`, as the table structure was not given. What I've shown is a basic example.

Comment: i don´t think i explained myself clearly, what i want to do is, when i click on a button named "edit", i have a textbox that, when i type the name of the row, i want that row to be changed, my issue is i don´t want a single row to be changed everytime, the row has to be specified on the textbox.

Comment: It was said `...my objective is to edit only one row with the text from the textbox`, which is how that is _typically_ done. Other than that, you may have to append information to the question (not in another comment) details of your perceived handling.

Comment: I think what OP meant is that he wants to select a cell in the [Drills (according to the norm EN 61439-2) column and then change its text through a txtbox when pressing a button

Comment: @FilipeAlmeida. Ok, I can (some what) see that. Perhaps the event handler writing to the DB is the confusion here? (which appears to be so, based on the comment upvotes) Anyway, if you have a solution to what's being asked, then go ahead, I don't mind removing my answer.

Comment: No I don't at all, I would have posted if I did, I just read comments from OP up there